# Check permission and log download with PHP, but use original link to download the file?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to check if a user has permission to download a file and to log that s/he downloaded it. It works good, but the files are hosted on Dropbox and I assume that the files are downloading through my server? I have recently gotten CPU spikes and complete server stalls so I'm looking into the option of either optimizing my code below if possible, or make so the access check and download count happens and then you're redirected to the dropbox link. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
/* PHP code here (not included in this snippet) to check for access and log download */

session_write_close();
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.mov\"");
       header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

// Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.

readfile('https://dropboxlink...');

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, `readfile` will read the file and then write the output so the file goes through your server. You could instead return a 301 or 302 redirect so the user requests the file from the other server instead. But I'm not sure if dropbox will allow or like that. You could instead download the file to your server and then serve it from there to other users requesting it, that way you only download it once.

Comment: It can be a lot of data so I want to avoid downloading at all if possible. How do I try the 301/302 trick? Any other solutions? Can I use ajax to validate/log and return the dropbox link and download it that way instead?

Comment: Actually I think a simple `header("location: https://dropboxlink...");` might have just done it instead of the code above! I had to replace a `?dl=0` at the end of the links to `?dl=1` to trigger the download, but that's easy!

Comment: instead of  readfile()  why not header('Location: dropboxurl');

Comment: @tim Yes, that's just what I did! Excellent!

Comment: :-) posts 2 seconds apart, glad it worked out for you

Comment: You probably want to use `file_get_contents` or even better `CURL`. `readfile` is only for local files on your server.

Comment: Hm, until I tried in Safari and it redirects in the same window instead of just asking if you want to download the file, like it works in FF and Chrome. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: @Variable I don't think I can install CURL on the server. Is `file_get_contents` also downloading the file to the server first? Any example of how that could look like?

Comment: @SeaBass No [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) gets literally the content of a the provided url (if it's accessable). You still need to code a function to save the 'downloaded' file to your server

Comment: Aaand, this seems to fix the Safari issue as well. I don't know the difference in how Dropbox is serving the files, but by running this `str_replace('www.dropbox.com/s/', 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/', $url);` Safari is acting like the other browsers.